# Saving a Pandas dataframe in fixed format with different column widths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fixed-width

I have a pandas dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
   A   B  C
0  1  10  1234
1  2  20  0
```

I want to save this dataframe in a fixed format. The fixed format I have in mind has different column width and is as follows:

"one space for column A's value then a comma then four spaces for column B's values and a comma and then five spaces for column C's values"

Or symbolically:

```
-,----,-----
```

My dataframe above (df) would look like the following in my desired fixed format:

```
1,  10, 1234
2,  20,    0
```

How can I write a command in Python that saves my dataframe into this format?

Comment: P.S. The dataframe is large and has more than 25 million rows so writing a "for i in rows" loop is not an option.

Comment: df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda t: (' '*(4-len(str(t)))+str(t))) and similar for the third column, then save to csv

Comment: @mathisfun You are a genius. I loved how simple and efficient this command is. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mathisfun I wish I could pick your answer as the best answer but since it is posted as a comment but not an answer, I cannot

Comment: I added it. Feel free to give me some street cred. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda t: (' '*(4-len(str(t)))+str(t)))
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda t: (' '*(5-len(str(t)))+str(t)))
df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv', index=False)
```